# Strange PPTP Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, vpn, rdp, pptp

I have a Windows PPTP VPN Tunnell  that I connect to. This terminates on a Win2k8 Server. 
I authenciate fine to the VPN. I can RDP to my admin workstation fine and from this I can RDP to all of the clients I want to connect to.

When I try and RDP to any other client on the network (same domain) this fails. The Laptop I am connecting from is a Win7 Pro on the same domain as well as the other clients.

I have checked the config of the VPN and this is all ok. it looks more like a client issue but I cant figure it out.

**Edit**

I can browse to UNC shares on the servers I am trying to connect to so I know its not a VPN issue.

Was working this morning. No changes no installs etc. Works off a different client so has to be the client.

Comment: Are you the administrator of this VPN, or just a user?

Comment: Mark, admin of the network. It's got me stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am immediately suspicious that a host-based firewall on the RDP servers you're attempting to access is blocking your attempts. If there were a less restrictive rule in place for the "File and Print Sharing" service on those same machines you could get the symptom you're seeing where accessing shared files on a given machine works but RDP to that machine does not.

You should also be sure that you have no client-side software blocking the RDP connection attempts or any filtering devices between you and the servers blocking them as well.

Edit:

On the basis of your comment re: it "working this morning" I'd offer up an experience I had where I'd left audio redirection enabled in the RDP client and had trouble accessing other machines when the audio hardware driver on that client started acting crazy. My RDP connection attempts would "freeze" for a long period at "Configuring remote session..." and I would eventually kill the RDP client. Turning off audio redirection caused the problem to stop (and, ultimately, re-installing the audio driver on the client cleared everything up).

Assuming you've rebooted the client and still see problems you might try paring down your options in the RDP client to see if things get better.

What is the specific error message or failure indication that you are seeing?

Comment: Was working this morning. No changes no installs etc. Works off a different client so has to be the client.

Comment: @t1nt1n: That's a fairly valuable piece of information for someone trying to answer your question and I've added it to your text.

Comment: Gave you the anwser as it prompted me to check the defult.rdp file. I had been doing some funky things with it and it was a bit messed up. Deleted it and recreated it all working now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can get an IP of one of the systems you CANNOT connect to try connecting by IP.  If that works, the issue is DNS.  I have seen cases where the ISPs DNS is used rather than the VPN DNS.  However, it ususally means no resolutions work.

Comment: I'll try this in the morning.